# How do you remove duplicate rows in Access?

Tags: ms-access-2013

I want to remove duplicate rows within my database.

I only want them removed if each field within that row matches another within the same table.

I've researched how to use the Query wizard to find duplicate fields, but I haven't found a way to match the entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to perform queries?

```
DELETE FROM table_name
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT
     MIN(RowId) as RowId,
     column_name1,
     column_name2,
     column_name3
   FROM
     table_name
   GROUP BY 
     column_name1,
     column_name2,
     column_name3
) as nonDuplicates ON
   table_name.RowId = nonDuplicates.RowId
WHERE
   nonDuplicates.RowId IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes I'm able to perform queries. My end goal is to get this to work manually then add it to my C# program to execute the queries when importing new reports to confirm there are no duplicate rows in the table, but I wanted to keep the question simple.

Comment: Then that should work. I would give you an SQL fiddle, but it seems like I'm not allowed to perform a delete statement there.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm removing the duplicates from the new table when a match is found within the original table? (LEFT OUTER JOIN returns matches found in both, and then is deleting them?)

Comment: What you mean new table? This query basically sets up a pseudo-table of your original table, compare the two, looks for duplicates, deletes the duplicates, and leaves the non-duplicate rows intact. If you're worried, take a backup of your current database / table before firing the SQL.

Comment: Ya, you're right I'll just dive in and learn along the way. Thanks for the help.